# How to make a folder on another server pc in ColdFusion 9 with cfdirectory

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdirectory

Currently I am trying to make a folder with the following code:

```
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="\\192.168.1.152\abc(that's my shared folder)\xyz" type="dir">
```

- I am using win xp home edition and the other side is windows server 2008.
- I am running my ColdFusion 9 application service as a user that I have made on the server.
- It gave me error that folder already exists. But when I check, there is no folder (xyz)

Please give me any configuration on win server 2008 or ColdFusion 9 server.

Comment: does it give you the same error if you remove `type="dir"` ? That's only required when you do a list

Comment: yes its gave me same error without type="dir".

Comment: And you've verified that the user/pass on both machines are the same? Are you able to list the contents of the abc directory from your share using ColdFusion?

Comment: yes user name is same but cf9 app service only accept password which is my machine's password.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but can't list the contents of the abc directory using ColdFusion.

Answer (score 0):

I would try accessing a mount (http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/mountvol.mspx?mfr=true) or using a symbolic link (mklink) and access it as a normal folder.